# Thermostat relay access

Tags: electrical, thermostat, relay

After nearly 30 years in my 1950s-era home, I'm finally getting around to finishing the basement. I'd like to put up a drywall ceiling, but this device, which I believe is the thermostat relay (to a gas-fired boiler), is in the way:

[image]

My main question, which was "does it require an access panel?" was answered quickly in the comment from Ecnerwal - with the additional benefit of correcting my assertion that junction boxes could be covered with drywall. Thank you!

Secondary to that, can I rotate it 90 degrees, so the wires don't protrude below the joist line? (I imagine once I open it up I can get a model number, and find the specs for it, but if you happen to know ...)

I'll be removing that ceiling box and a receptacle on the same circuit, since they're not needed any more and are not to code.

I'm a little curious about the unused white wire - it's free, not attached in the thermostat box either. Seems like it could be used as ground, which wasn't required when the house was built, so there is no ground in the supply line. I don't know when this relay was installed, or why they used this cable - I'm assuming it was the original, and the white wire had a purpose at some point.

Thanks very much in advance, for any thoughts or comments!

Comment: Junction boxes ***can't*** "disappear behind the ceiling", so if that's been your belief, you may have BIG problems - junction boxes must remain accessible "forever" without the use of tools. A drop ceiling where you can lift out panels is OK, drywall is not, to maintain access.

Comment: Thank you!! The only reason I thought that is because I've "discovered" some hidden boxes in this old house, but now that you mention it, right!! (An electrician who removed a light fixture ages ago told me that, and properly installed a cover plate.) Fortunately I haven't added to the problem ... :-)

Comment: Please remove the part about the thermostat full of insulation and ask that (with pictures) as a separate question. Multiple questions at once are just fine here, however, multiple questions in one really aren't. Spend a moment taking the [tour] to get more info.

Comment: @FreeMan you're absolutely right, thank you. Even the bit about the white wire is typical of my rambling thought process, but at least it's in the picture!

Comment: The "white wire" may just be a wire not used by the thermostat setup.